# How to move forward with Laplace transform of $e^{i(5t)}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, laplace-transform

I'm trying to solve the Laplace transform of $e^{i(5t)}$. This is my work so far:

$$\begin{align} \mathcal{L}\{ e^{i(5t)}\} &= \int_0^\infty e^{-st} e^{i(5t)} \ dt \\ &= \int_0^\infty e^{-t(s - 5i)} \ dt \end{align}$$

Doing the change of variables $u = -t(s - 5i) = t(5i - s)$, we get

$$\begin{align} \int_0^\infty e^{-t(s - 5i)} \ dt &= -\dfrac{1}{s - 5i} \int_0^{\infty (5i - s)} e^u \ du \\ &= \dfrac{1}{5i - s} \left[ e^u \right]^{\infty (5i - s)}_0 \end{align}$$

But then we need to consider the value of $\infty(5i - s)$. For Laplace transforms, I think we require that $\Re(s - 5i) = \Re(s) > 0$ for convergence, right? I'm a bit confused with how to move forward here. Can someone please explain this? Thank you.

Comment: One more thing.. If $u = t(5i-s)$, then $du = ?$

Comment: @Ak19 Thanks for that. Look ok now?

Comment: This kind fo analysis is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$\int_0^\infty e^{-(s-5i)t}\,dt=\left[-\frac{e^{-(s-5i)t}}{s-5i}\right]_0^\infty=-\frac1{s-5i}\left[\frac{e^{5it}}{e^{st}}\right]_0^\infty=-\frac1{s-5i}[0-1]=\frac1{s-5i}$$ since $\left|e^{5it}/e^{st}\right|\le1/e^{st}\to0$ as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please clarify the convergence condition? Was I correct that it is $\Re(s - 5i) = \Re(s) > 0$?

Comment: Yes, one way to see this is that $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}e^{5it}/e^{st}$ must be finite, and this can only be achieved if $\Re s>0$. Only the real part matters as the imaginary part is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: write $e^{i5t}$ as $\cos (5t)+i\sin (5t)$ and use integration by parts for each of the two terms.

Comment: My goal is to solve it by directly using the definition of Laplace transform.